# анимация из Maya в Unity запекается с некорректным поворотом сустава/кости

Tags: unity3d

начинается ещё в maya при запекании анимационного клипа с помощью запекания ключей в скелет через key ->bake animation. скелет -не human ik. после запекания сустав не сгибается на полный угол, только частично. после импорта в юнити ещё меньше сгиб, что-то не вычислю никак причину

Comment: масштаб везде 1?

Comment: вроде 1ин                   111        1 1

Comment: мда, не могу осилить пока что. если я выгибаю контроллер сильнее - на выходе нужный угол, но он всякий раз меньше чем в Maya. появилось после того, как распотрошил модель для корректив направлений костей(не мог ragdoll коллайдеры нормально повесить), анимации создавались на старом скелете, теперь перекочевали в новый с малыми коррективами. в итоге имею 2а импортированных в unity скелета. на старом - всё ок, на новом -rotate суставов с ограничениями...

Comment: Вылечил поставив галочку на Bake Animation при импорте из Maya(даже хотя анимация в скелет и была предварительно запечена через key ->bake animation)

Comment: эй нормальные дайте отвечать на вопросы